# sending textview data in android to server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache

```
this code is running correctly.but the problem is.it is not saving text view value in data base. please help me.
```

when onclick button is executed the data should fetch to data base.but its is not showing any thing in data base.

i converted the lat lang values into string and after that it is converted into address format. iam calling the string values of lat lang into data base.it is not showing any thing.

```
public class Cam extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String lat="", lon="";
    String ret = "";
    TextView tv;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cam);

        Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddress);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) Cam.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                // Define a listener that responds to location updates
                LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                        lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                        lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
                        tv.setText(GetAddress(lat, lon));
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                };
                // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });
    }

    public String GetAddress(String lat, String lon)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon), 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                new getresult().execute();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ret = "Can't get Address!";
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public class getresult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String result = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locat", ret));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                        "utf-8"));
                result = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        new BasicResponseHandler());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your server side code? i think the probelm may be at your server side code

Comment: $locat= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['locat']);$sql="INSERT INTO details (land_mark, descrip, phonenum, location)
VALUES ('$landmark', '$description', '$phonenumber', '$locat')";

Comment: server side code is correct.no problem with that.

Comment: just print $locat value on server to make sure that the correct value is posted from your android to server

Comment: how to print that value. and where??please provide me any reference.